# IOCHK from fortran

Tags: fortran

I am using fortran 11.0.035 compiler version on visual studio 2005. Please check the following code which is giving wrong result for me. I am not getting the problem.

```
IF(IOCHK.NE.0)THEN  //this condition is true
cscl    begin pipewrite
cscl  PRINT 479,IOCHK
4791    Buffer=' '
WRITE(Buffer,479,ERR=99479,IOSTAT=iPipeErr)IOCHK
```

Above code is cludeds piping concept in client server programming and is from server side. Client should give some information to the server, but it is not sending information. So I am getting buffer data as empty.

For what `IOCHK` will be used? Why I am unable to execute the above code successfully?

Answer (score 1):

`IOCHK` = I/O Channel Check, it's the interface for I/O error handling/detecting. In FORTRAN it's (likely to be) the I/O check switch. If it is unequal to zero then some I/O error occured.